# How does the resonant frequency of a glass slab depend on its thickness

Tags: acoustics, resonance, vibrations, glass

I am interested in finding out how does the thickness of a glass slab change the resonant frequency of it. Since i know that resonant frequency not only depends on the material but also on the topology of the material.

any theoretical framework know, or how to derive it pls let me know.

I searched for this but am getting only the wine glass experiment, but not with an uniform glass slab

Comment: This is a complex topic! You can find some info about the acoustics of bars, but that mostly concentrates on wooden or metal bars, eg https://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.2015478 & https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1359520 Thomas Rossing wrote extensively on these kinds of resonators, but there has been important work in recent years. FWIW, many years ago, I heard a xylophone that used glass bars. It had a lovely sound.

Comment: The resonant modes will depend on how you excite the sound too. You may hit it, rub it, couple it with a sound source.